# how to convert TensorFlow Conv2D with kernel_regularizer into PyTorch

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, convolution

hello I have a layer defined as bellow:

**tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=1, kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(l=0.05))**

right now I would like to convert it into PyTorch but I don't know how. Can anyone help?

Comment: What are you trying to do with this layer?